# unexpected kEND

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

```
  1 <p>
  2   <b>Name:</b>                                 
  3   <%=h @findlist.name %>                       
  4 </p>
  5 
  6 <p>
  7   <b>Cached slug:</b>                          
  8   <%=h @findlist.cached_slug %>                
  9 </p>
 10     
 11 <h4>Products</h4>                              
 12 <% @findlist.products.each do |product| %>    
 13 <p>
 14   <b>Product:</b>
 15   <%=h image_tag(product.photo.url) %>         
 16 </p>
 17 <% end %>                                     
 18                                                
 19 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_findlist_path(@user, @findlist) %> |
 20 <%= link_to 'Back', findlists_path %>
```

I currently have the above code but it gives me the "unexpected kEND, expecting $end" at around line #12. I have been testing and testing the code and I can't see the syntax error. I am a ruby and rails newbie and I probably just couldn't see it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** removing lines 12 to 17 removes the syntax error

Controller code:

```
  7   def show
  8     @findlist = @user.findlists.all
  9   end
```

I am using rails 2.3.11

Comment: well, i don't see something on first sight, could you please provide the controller code ? by the way, if you use rails 3 you can remove the h after <%

Comment: What does `@findlist.products` evaluate to in the template?

Comment: also, include :products in your find. This prevents from doing the same things twice. Check more on eager loading if you're interested.

Comment: it was an error in copy and pasting. unbelievable :P

Comment: Seems ok, time to do some <%= debug @findlist %> and the same with products to check what is inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get @findlists and traverse @findlist :) Is this really the error though ? Or a mistake on pasting code here ? Because i see that you use @findlist before each.

The error is from another file.- from comment

Comment: Actually that wasn't the error. It was from another file... the model. Your comment above is probably close enough as it was from another file. I edited your comment to reflect this.

Comment: i'm a bit confused. The above code you pasted is controller code for the presented view ? I suppose not. If not, could you display the correct one ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at what findlist and products actually are, but if @findlist is a list of things, and each thing has products, then you need to break out into a sub-loop.

```
<% @findlist.each do |list| %>
   <% list.products.each do |product| %>    
     <p>
       <b>Product:</b>
       <%=h image_tag(product.photo.url) %>         
     </p>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```